# Printing out every number in a "long" datatype in java

Tags: java, long-integer, illegalargumentexception, println

I tried printing out every individual number in a `long` datatype but I get this error message after about 1,000,000,000 numbers:

> IllegalArgumentException: Illogical text range from 1072890159 to -1072593439

How can I continue past this point?

```
long tot = 0;
while (tot < 9223372036854775807L)
{
    //This for loop makes sure that instead of printing out 200 000 numbers in 27 sec it
    //will take less than 3 seconds to print out about 500 000 numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        tot = tot + 10; 
        System.out.print(tot+" "+(tot+1)+" "+(tot+2)+" "+(tot+3)+" "+(tot+4)+" "+(tot+5)
                            +" "+(tot+6)+" "+(tot+7)+" "+(tot+8)+" "+(tot+9)+" "); 
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: This is 2^63 values; even if you printed one value per nanosecond (probably at least 3 orders of magnitude faster than reality), it would take 300 years to print the whole thing.

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using Netbeans?

Comment: This is a bug on NetBeans indeed https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=181582

Answer (score 0):

You're NOT „*printing out every individual number in a `long` datatype*“ with this code snippet.

Firstly, you start printing positive numbers from 10 on. Try it with `byte` to check but be prepared to abort the run quickly, since...

Secondly, the `while` loop never ends. Why this?

Well, once you have spent appx. 150 years (according to  *Oliver Charlesworth*'s calculation mentioned in the comments) `tot` in the `while` header becomes `9,223,372,036,854,700,000`.
(`tot` is always a multiple of `100,000` after the `for` loop due to the `‹0..9,999› < 10000` and the `+ 10` therein.)

The following will be printed in that `while` cycle (line breaks and formatting added for easier reading):

```
 ...
 9223372036854775800  9223372036854775801  9223372036854775802
 9223372036854775803  9223372036854775804  9223372036854775805
 9223372036854775806  9223372036854775807 -9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775807 -9223372036854775806 -9223372036854775805
-9223372036854775804 -9223372036854775803 -9223372036854775802
 ...
```

This is known as [*(arithmetic) overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow).

Such `tot` will be less, since negative, than `9223372036854775807L`, a.k.a. `Long.MAX_VALUE`, for another appx. 150 years until it becomes positive again and then the whole cycle starts again, over and over.

Why does this happen?

Well, there is *one and only one* value of `tot` that can make `(tot < 9223372036854775807L)` evaluate to `false` to leave the `while` loop: exactly this `9_223_372_036_854_775_807L`, a.k.a `Long.MAX_VALUE`, since there is no bigger `long` value than this.

But you are "hiding" this number inside the `for` loop (see output above and remember that `tot` is always a multiple of 100,000 outside the `for` loop) so that `(tot < 9223372036854775807L)` never gets the chance to evaluate against it.

I'd implement it as follows:

```
public class Integers {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        printNumbersBetween(Byte.MIN_VALUE, Byte.MAX_VALUE);
        printNumbersBetween(Short.MIN_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        printNumbersBetween(Character.MIN_VALUE, Character.MAX_VALUE);
        // printNumbersBetween(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        // printNumbersBetween(Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE);

    } // main(...)

    public static void printNumbersBetween(final long minValue, final long maxValue) {

        long n = minValue;
        while (n < maxValue) {
            // Count of numbers to be printed at once is preferably a power of two,
            // since the counts of numbers in the domains of all primitives divide nicely by it.
            // Such avoiding having to extra handle the last print cycle which is not "full".
            // E.g.: byte -> 256 numbers -> (discouraged) chunks of 10 -> 25 * 10 + 6[!].
            System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d%n",
                n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++, n++);
        }

    } // printNumbersBetween(...)

} // Integers
```

---

Apart from the above let me leave some comments concerning your coding style:

- `9223372036854775807L` is as bad as [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) can be. `9_223_372_036_854_775_807L`  (since Java 7) would be slightly better but `Long.MAX_VALUE` is provided by the Java API exactly for this.
- I agree, one can argue whether `tot += 10` or `tot = tot + 10;` is preferred. I don't cling on that.
- The lines:

  ```
  System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d ",
      tot, tot+1, tot+2, tot+3, tot+4, tot+5, tot+6, tot+7, tot+8, tot+9);`
  ```

  compared to:

  ```
  System.out.print(tot+" "+(tot+1)+" "+(tot+2)+" "+(tot+3)+" "+(tot+4)+" "+(tot+5)
                      +" "+(tot+6)+" "+(tot+7)+" "+(tot+8)+" "+(tot+9)+" ");
  ```

  are much easier to read and comprehend, aren't they? And it's shorter, too.
- Creating an implicite instance of (an empty) `String` in `System.out.println("");` is pointless.